# WebViewController - display

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have created WebViewController view, which displays websites 
in Menu. I have two cells, Contact us, on click of cell it shows web view with contact and Terms of use displays terms .

My question is how to write code which uses one of the controller.

// This controller display web

```
class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    var urlToShow:String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let url = urlToShow {
            webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code of where u add the value to `urlToShow`

Comment: Do you mean you want to use web view controller for all of them ? Without duplicating 3?

Comment: @AaoIi yes  I use one conntroller which display webside                                     Contact us this links http://www.doctena.com/doctena-lu-contact/
or http://www.doctena.com/doctena-be-contact/
or http://www.doctena.com/doctena-nl-contact/ and Terms of use http://www.doctena.com/doctena-lu-terms-of-use/
or http://www.doctena.com/doctena-be-terms-of-use/
or http://www.doctena.com/doctena-nl-terms-of-use/

Comment: @MagdalenaDziesińska where is your web view controller ? I mean in Storyboard or xib file ? Is it linked to navigation controller or not ? Please provide me with this details so I can help up correctly !

Comment: @MagdalenaDziesińska have you try my answer?

Answer (score -1):

You should use SFSafariViewController instead of any webviewViewController.

```
if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil) {
        SFSafariViewController *sfvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
        sfvc.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:sfvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL]) {
            //NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[URL description]);
        }
    }
```

Pass different URL for contact and privacy policy. It will open website in looks like navigated in your application.
Thanks

Comment: This question is tagged "swift". Your solution may have value, but is not written in the language requested by OP, so it's off-topic. Please provide an answer in Swift. Thank you.

Comment: Got -1. Great. Will never add help on Stack again.

Comment: Why would you give up so easily? First of all you know what you have to do to improve your answer, just read my comment... And anyway it's just *one* downvote - which will probably be removed if you fix your answer. If you have knowledge to share, don't rage quit for such little inconvenience, instead learn how to make good answers. :)